# MKAnnotationView disappearing on swipe and double-tap zoom

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, mkmapview, drawrect, mkannotation

I have subclassed MKAnnotationView to create an annotation that basically draws a circle around a point on a map view through override of drawRect.  The circle draws fine in the following situations (in the simulator):

- On initial load of the map view
- On swipe, but only when swipe motion is stopped before touch ends (so that map doesn't "coast" after touch ends)
- On pinch zoom

The circle will disappear when any of the following actions occur:

- Swipe where map "coasts" after touch ends
- Double-tap zoom

The circle will reappear if any of the actions in the "working" group are taken after it has disappeared.

What might cause this?  I'm not a draw/display/layout expert (frankly, I'm not an obj C or iPhone expert either).

Here is some slightly simplified code that seems most relevant from my MKAnnotationView subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
 [self drawCircleAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0) withRadius:self.radiusInPixels andColor:self.circleAnnotation.color];
}


- (void)drawCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint)p withRadius:(int)r {
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    float alpha = 0.75;

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 255, 0, 0, alpha);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 255, 0, 0, alpha);

    // Draw a circle (border only)
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 2*r, 2*r));
}
```

Comment: also seeing this behavior, looking for a solution…

Comment: even I am facing same problem , any luck ?

Comment: is the drawRect called at all in the "non" working group?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only my views don't implement drawRect, and they dissappear UNLESS the mapview coasts to a stop!

Answer (score 2):

Did you add this method?

```
- (void)setAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    [super setAnnotation:annotation];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This is taken from Apple's sample code app called WeatherMap which was removed from Apple Developer Center, but can be found on github
https://github.com/acekiller/iOS-Samples/blob/master/WeatherMap/Classes/WeatherAnnotationView.m

Comment: The weather annotations in the sample code disappear and re-appear after every drag/ zoom.

Comment: That's because they implemeted it that way, see '- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)map regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated' method in 'MapViewController.m'

Comment: Can you please let me know where should I put this code? As your provided link is not available anymore.

Comment: Sure, it should be in your custom subclass of MKAnnotationView as indicated in the question. Seems Apple has removed their sample code, but I found it on github: https://github.com/acekiller/iOS-Samples/blob/master/WeatherMap/Classes/WeatherAnnotationView.m